# White space character regex chrome / nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js, google-chrome

Why using \s the regex return false?

```
r =  new RegExp("Flickr\:( ).");
r.text("Flickr: bla bla bla bla!") // return true;

r =  new RegExp("Flickr\:\s.");
r.text("Flickr: bla bla bla bla!") // return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should always escape `\` character in strings:

```
r =  new RegExp("Flickr:\\s.");
r.test("Flickr: bla bla bla bla!") // true
```

You could use special regex syntax to avoid "double escaping":

```
r =  /Flickr:\s./;
r.test("Flickr: bla bla bla bla!") // true
```

Comment: and it takes 6(!) slashes to represent escaped special char. `(new RegExp('\\\\\\$')).test('\\$');`